# Webhook and API (Definition and Differences)

Tags: rest, http, webhooks

I want to know about webhook (what is webhook). What is the application of webhook (a real world scenario). Besides, what are the differences between webhook and API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An API is a standardised way of communicating with a service. You've tagged `REST` in your question so I'll focus on RESTful APIs using HTTP but it is important to know that API is a very generic term.

In the REST world everything is a resource and you use the HTTP methods to define what action you want to take on or apply to that resource. For example, to list all the users on GitHub you would send a `GET` request to https://api.github.com/users. The URL (specifically the `/users` part) defines what resource you are interested in. Here the resource is a collection of all the users. There's other methods you can use; such as `PUT` to create or update a resource. To learn more about the different methods you can read the [HTTP specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3).

Webhooks are often used in conjunction with APIs but they are focused on events. They allow a service to send out 'notifications' when an event happens or some condition is met.

GitHub is again a good example of what webhooks are used for. Say I'm building a service which sends out an email every time someone leaves a comment on an issue in GitHub. I could use the GitHub API (like above) to list all of the comments on an issue and then check if there have been any new comments since the last time I checked. I can then just repeat this request every few seconds. This is known as [polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science)). The issue here is that most of the time I'm checking the result is not going to change. This is going to be a waste of resources.
Webooks allow for [Event-Driven Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming). Instead of randomly checking I can instruct GitHub to send my service a HTTP request every time a comment is added: aka a webhook. In this architecture I only have to send a request to GitHub's API when I know for sure that a new comment has been left.

Overall, you cannot really compare APIs and webhooks. The link between them is  simply that webhooks send requests to APIs.